# How to show data from two different datasources in Activereport

Tags: activereports

I have a report file . I have to show the data in this report from two different datatable . I have to show the data from  one  datatable after another . I don't want to use sub report . Is there another way to solve it?

With Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to solve this with ActiveReports *is* with a subreport. Other than using subreports, you could use the "unbound mode" to programmatically combine the records from both datatables into a single rowset.  See [this walkthrough](http://www.datadynamics.com/Help/ActiveReports6/arWLKGroupOnUnboundFields.html) for an example of using unbound mode (see the DataInitialize and FetchData events for the meat of the matter).

It is difficult to say for sure how best to go about this without more information though. For example, some info that might useful:

- Are the data tables in the DataSet?
- Are the datatables joinable? In other words, is there a relation between them?
- Why don't you want to use subreports? This is truly the way a banded report writer like ActiveReports is meant to handle multiple data sources.

Also, you might check out our [Data Dynamics Reports product](http://www.datadynamics.com/DataDynamicsReports). It uses a different paradigm than banded reports where you lay out data regions (e.g. table, chart, etc.) on a page. Each data region can be bound to a separate data source without using a subreport. Maybe that would be a better fit for what you need.

```
Scott Willeke
GrapeCity inc.
```